# SpaceX Crew Dragon depressurization for emergency EVA

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2, eva

As far as I know, the Crew Dragon does not have an airlock. Therefore, if astronauts inside needed to go outside for some reason, they'd need to suit up, depressurize the cabin, and then they'd be able to open the door.

- Does the crew dragon's LSS have the capability to evacuate the cabin of air (and re-pressurize it from vacuum)?
- How damaging would this operation be to the contents and electronics of the crew dragon capsule?

Comment: Logic ( or perhaps "common sense design planning" ) would hopefully say yes to your first part question, even if it was some very crude rudimentary venting valve or similar device but I could not fathom a reason to not include such a device, provided accidental operation was fully fail safe. Interested in this so will see what those more learnedly have to say.

Comment: Might be worth reading up on the capabilities of the Apollo capsule & what was designed to be possible or unallowed so far as EVA went.

Comment: The Commercial Crew vehicles are required to be able of protecting the crew in the event of a loss of cabin pressure. https://web.archive.org/web/20120328055242/http://commercialcrew.nasa.gov/document_file_get.cfm?docid=107 That implies that the onboard systems must be able to withstand vacuum (your 2nd bullet). However, the Commercial Crew vehicles won't be carrying EVA suits, so an EVA from them is impossible. (While I believe this last statement to be true, I have no reference, so posting as a comment).

Comment: Piggy-backing on OM's comment, it is interesting to note that, anecdotally, I believe there is a move afoot to examine the EVA capabilities of NASA's current IVA suits (the Launch and Entry Suit, or LES). The juicy details are, I'm sure, proprietary...

Comment: If the Crew Dragon capsule has a leak and the astronauts should survive in their suits, the electronics of the capsule must work in a vacuum too.

Comment: Think about accidents a suit is for: Valve left open, window breaks, hatch jammed and unable to close, meteor hole in hull. A tethered suit can only save the astronauts in the 1st case, because cabin air could be restored. In all the other cases, they are in a wait-to-die scenario because they can only survive by leaving the ship. They could not reenter the atmosphere, or enter the ISS with a broken window or jammed hatch. If they had a small air & power pack that could support a 20 minute EVA, the suit's utility would be much greater. I think it's nuts that they don't have that.